# "ORA-01843: not a valid month" error Oracle SQL

Tags: oracle, date

Please help. I making a minor mistake here but I am not able to find it even after reading the previous questions.

```
SELECT TRUNC (SYSDATE) - TO_DATE (open_date_txt, 'yyyy-mm-dd') AS Days_open
FROM 'table'
WHERE TRUNC (SYSDATE) - TO_DATE (open_date_txt, 'yyyy-mm-dd') > 90 AND
      TRUNC (SYSDATE) - TO_DATE (open_date_txt, 'yyyy-mm-dd') < 120
```

The query runs without an error but when I select all the data from the results(by doing ctrl+A), I get ORA-1843: not a valid month.

NLS_DATE_FORMAT is  DD-MON-RR
NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE is AMERICAN

The table has 2 columns, and the open_date_txt field is stored as varchar2(10) in the database. Please see below

```
Name    open_date_txt
AA      2010-03-24
BB      2010-07-23
CC      2015-09-20
DD      1997-03-25
```

Thank you.

Also,I'm struck with incorrect data model. This date field has values like '0--' , month values greater than 12 , and finally days greater than 31. Now I want to ignore these records during my select. The stored procedures I created doesn't work fine, any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I think you need to show us the table data, or at least a representative sample of it.

Comment: The table has 2 columns, please see below

Comment: No... _don't_ post data in a comment.  Update your question.

Comment: The table has 2 columns, and the open_date_txt field is stored as varchar2(10) in the database. Please see below

Name open_date_txt
AA      2010-03-24
BB  2010-07-23
CC  2015-09-20
DD   1997-03-25

Thank you.

Comment: Just an aside: a convenient way to avoid writing out the whole expression multiple times would be: `SELECT days_open FROM ( SELECT TRUNC (SYSDATE) - TO_DATE (open_date_txt, 'yyyy-mm-dd') AS days_open
FROM 'table' ) WHERE days_open > 90 AND days_open < 120`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error implies that there is at least one row in the table where the value in `open_date_txt` cannot be converted to a `DATE` using the given format string.

The query will run until it hits that row, then throw the error.  Of course, you never see the row that causes the error in your output, so it is hard to find the value causing the problem.

One technique is to go through row by row and raise a more useful exception that identifies the entry causing the error.  For example:

```
DECLARE
  d DATE;
BEGIN
  FOR x IN (SELECT name, open_date_txt FROM table) LOOP
    BEGIN
      d := TO_DATE( x.open_date_txt, 'yyyy-mm-dd');
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN others THEN
        raise_application_error(-20000, 'Error on name: ' || x.name, TRUE );
    END;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

You could also modify this to print out the name for the row and continue, so you'd find if there are multiple rows with bad data.

Comment: Dave, the thought crossed my mind that he may have some whitespace problem.  If so, then using `TRIM(open_date_txt)` might be helpful.

Comment: Might be.  But isn't it better to find the data causing the error than to guess?

Comment: I agree.  I'll study your code so that I may use it myself at some point.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen and DaveCosta, I was able to find bad data in the table. Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: And now you also learned why it is bad to store dates as strings.

Comment: I'm struck with incorrect data model. This date field has values like '0--' , month values greater than 12 , and finally days greater than 31. Now I want to ignore these records during my select. The stored procedures I created doesn't work fine, any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: One idea is to create your own function TO_DATE_NO_EXCEPTIONS.  In it you would call TO_DATE using the given arguments and trap any exceptions, returning NULL when an exception occurs.  Then in your query you can call this function instead of TO_DATE, and if desired filter out the rows where it returns a NULL.